# How to read msi log

Tags: logging, windows-installer

I try to trouble shoot install as it fails recently.
I have the following part in my install log file, but do not know how to read/interpret it. 
Can anyone point the doc or resources?
thanks a lot!

```
MSI (s) (78:A8) [21:14:26:012]: Doing action: viewer.exe
Action start 21:14:26: viewer.exe.
MSI (s) (78:A8) [21:14:26:012]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (78:A8) [21:14:26:022]: Transforming table CustomAction.

MSI (s) (78:A8) [21:14:26:022]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (78:A8) [21:14:26:022]: Transforming table Binary.

Action ended 21:14:56: viewer.exe. Return value 1.
```

Edit 
I found one link which is to tell how to interpret msi log 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the Windows SDK, wilogutl.exe will help. Along with the rest of the documentation :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372811(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a detailed article on [how to read MSI log files](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html).

If you're an Advanced Installer user you can also leverage the built-in log parser/debugger from the application, however all the advices from the article can be applied for any MSI log file, no matter if you open it with Notepad, Notepad++ or in any other tool.